# How to add "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as Content-type in .Net httpClient

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-headers

I cannot add Content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". There is throwing an error. Only for the this content-type. Thank You for the attention.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = new HttpMethod("POST"),
        RequestUri = new Uri(path),
    }; 

    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    var token = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

It's throwing error like that

> "Misused header name, 'Content-Type'. Make sure request headers are
> used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with
> HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type is a header of the content, not of the request, which is why this is failing.

**One way** is that you can call `TryAddWithoutValidation` instead of add like below:

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

**The other way** is that you can set the Content-Type when creating the request content itself, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67614456/11398810).

Comment: Your second way is working for me. Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'v used something more complicated but it works.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //headers dictionary
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //request
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url)) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
        req.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencode"));
        var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
```